# Laravel migration to change an unsignedMediumInteger column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-migrations

I have a need to create a migration that changes an existing 'unsignedMediumInteger' column to nullable().

I have the following in my migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use AppNew\Models\SubscriptionType;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('subscription_types', function ($table) {
            $table->unsignedMediumInteger('max_number_of_employees')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
};
```

This throws an error as below:

```
  INFO  Running migrations.  

  2023_10_25_103141_make_subscription_types_max_number_of_employees_field_nullable  108ms FAIL

   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception 

  Unknown column type "mediuminteger" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

...any pointers as to get around this please?

Thanks, K...

Comment: What version of Laravel do you have installed, and which version of doctrine/dbal?

Comment: Googling, it seems to only be an issue when modifying a column, not creating it, because DBAL doesn't support mediumInteger. You may need to write the `ALTER TABLE` statement manually.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#modifying-columns-on-sqlite has a note that only certain columns can be modified. `mediumInteger` is not on that list.

Comment: Hi @aynber, Laravel 9 and DBAL 3.3 I believe.

When you say 'write the ALTER TABLE statement manually' do you mean like use raw SQL?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write the raw sql.

Comment: DB::statement("ALTER TABLE subscription_types MODIFY max_number_of_employees MEDIUMINT unsigned"); did the trick for me, thanks @aynber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) approach:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY COLUMN <column_name> MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NULL");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY COLUMN <column_name> MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL");
    }
};
```

Comment: Accepted this answer @Odin Thunder albeit aynber had already pointed me in that direction - thanks both.

DB::statement("ALTER TABLE subscription_types MODIFY max_number_of_employees MEDIUMINT unsigned");

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `DB::statement` method to execute a raw SQL statement with the `alter` query

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

return new class extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE subscription_types MODIFY max_number_of_employees MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NULL');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, there's no need to touch any packages. You can simply declare the `MediumInteger` type in your application and use it in the Doctrine DBAL package.

---

#### Requirements

- Laravel 8.x or higher
- Doctrine DBAL 3.x or higher

#### Solution

Create the class corresponding to our type based on the following template:

###### App\Database\Types\MediumInteger.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Database\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\IntegerType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 * Custom type for medium integer.
 */
class MediumInteger extends IntegerType
{
    // Important: leave it as is, Laravel Schema will look for it by this name
    const NAME = 'mediuminteger';

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        // getMediumIntTypeDeclarationSQL() not defined
        // return $platform->getMediumIntTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);

        // _getCommonIntegerTypeDeclarationSQL() protected, so cant call it
        // return 'MEDIUMINT' . $platform->_getCommonIntegerTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);

        // call the generation of Integer type, prepend the missing word MEDIUM
        return 'MEDIUM' . $platform->getIntegerTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        // This is executed when the value is read from the database. Make your conversions here, optionally using the $platform.
        return $value === null ? null : (int) $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        // This is executed when the value is written to the database. Make your conversions here, optionally using the $platform.
        return $value === null ? null : (int) $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

(#1 DBAL Native Declaration) Following this, declare it either globally or only in the migration where it's needed.

Important: Preferably use Laravel's built-in configuration file
instead of that.

```php
use App\Database\Types\MediumInteger;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

if (! Type::hasType(MediumInteger::NAME)) {
    Type::addType(MediumInteger::NAME, MediumInteger::class);
}
```

(#2 Laravel Declaration - RECOMMENDED) The Laravel framework provides the ability to declare custom types once we've created the corresponding classes for them. To achieve this, we need to follow the following pattern in the `config/database.php` file:

```php
use App\Database\Types\MediumInteger;

'dbal' => [
    'types' => [
        MediumInteger::NAME => MediumInteger::class,
    ],
],
```

---

#### More information

- [Custom Mapping Types](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) - Doctrine DBAL Docs
- [Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#modifying-columns-on-sqlite) - Laravel Docs